# Create more than two turtles and moving them

Tags: python-3.x, oop, python-3.6, turtle-graphics

How to make few turtles in a screen and make them move one at once?

Comment: can anyone help me please?

Comment: you can create next turtle `turtle2 = turtle.Turtle()` and use it `turtle2.goto(100, 100)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `turtle.Turtle()` to create many turtles and then you can use it one by one to make small move. Turtles will move almost at the same time.

```
import turtle

t1 = turtle.Turtle()
t2 = turtle.Turtle()

for x in range(36):
    # first turtle makes small move
    t1.left(10)  
    t1.forward(10)
    # second turtle makes small move
    t2.right(10)
    t2.forward(10)

turtle.done()
```

If you want to move all the time (and do other things at the same time)
then you can use `ontimer()` to make small moves.

```
import turtle

def move_t1():
    # first turtle makes small move
    t1.left(10)  
    t1.forward(10)

    # repeat after 100ms
    turtle.ontimer(move_t1, 100)

def move_t2():
    # second turtle makes small move
    t2.right(10)  
    t2.forward(10)

    # repeat after 100ms
    turtle.ontimer(move_t2, 100)

t1 = turtle.Turtle()
t2 = turtle.Turtle()

move_t1() # first turtle makes first move
move_t2() # second turtle makes first move

turtle.done()
```

Comment: well, the problem is I need to make a class for them. I need to make a class for Moth and for a light and need to keep track of the position of light. So, whenever the moth reach the radius of the light it dies. So, how can i do that? I need to have following functions compulsorily:
 a constructor init (self, initialPosition)
• a method move(self, newPosition)
• a method moveToLight(self, lightPosition)
• a method getPosition(self)

Comment: I have third example on GitHub [main-3.py](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/turtle/two-turtles-and-ontimer/main-3.py). It uses class for turtle. You can use left mouse button to add more turtles on screen, and right mouse button to stop/start all turtles.

Comment: your class should be similar to my class. `__init__` shoud be similar, `getPosition` should be easy - it should use `t.position()`. As for `move()` and `moveToLight` then should be similar and they should use `ontimer` to move turtle - or they should keep destination position in variable and run other function which use this variable to move turtle.

Comment: But how do i set a parameter for the light?

Comment: do you mean how to send lightposition to turtle or what ? You can create function which get light position and send to turtle and it uses `ontimer` to repeat it.

Comment: No, there's gotta be a parameter in which if Moth enters it dies

Comment: you can create class `Light` and then you can create instances with this parameter `light1 = Light(my_parameter_1)`, `light2 = Light(my_parameter_2)`  and keep it inside instances.

Comment: I don't why but when using timer it's making the light circle again. Not working

Comment: can you give me a comprehensive solution to the problem please? I have just been hard coding the problem so far

Comment: why do you use timer with `Light` ? you have to use timer only with functions which have to be repeated - like move, animation but not when you create object or object doesn't move.

Comment: can you do it for me please? because I am new to OOP I don't have much idea about it. So, may be I am doing something wrong somewhere and I am not noticing it

Comment: I put some example on GitHub: [moth-light](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/turtle/moth-light)